# android sql table update error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

When I try to update a table it does not return any error.But update not works.

Here is my insert and update query

Can anyone tell is there any problem?

My insert statement (working)

```
 public long insertValueWithOnDate(int ParameterId,String value,String date,String operation)
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_PARAMETER_ID, ParameterId);
    initialValues.put(KEY_UNIT_VALUE, value);
    initialValues.put(KEY_OPERATION, operation);
    initialValues.put(KEY_ON_DATE, date);
    initialValues.put(KEY_OFF_DATE, "");
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

My update statement (not working)

```
public void insertValueWithOfDate(int ParameterId,String value,String date,String operation)
{
    db.execSQL("update Entries set operation='"+operation+"',offdate='"+date+"',value='"+value+"' where parameterId='"+ParameterId+"' and operation='"+"onn"+"' and offdate='"+null+"'");
}
```

My table structure is as follows

```
    _id   parameterId   operation   ondate       offdate       value
--------------------------------------------------------------------
      1      1        on       15-03-2015       15-03-2015       0
      2      1        on       15-03-2015           null         0
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: That variable called null, is that an actual null? If so concatting null turns the entire string to null.

Comment: Also if you want to check on null you should not use =, but "is null" instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your where clause is wrong at the parameterId parameter:

```
...parameterId='"+ParameterId+"' ....
```

I guess parameterId is an int,so you should remove quotes:

```
...parameterId="+ParameterId+" ....
```

And also offdate parameter should be:

```
and offdate is null
```

Comment: That  wrks Thanks Alvaro